# Как объединить товары с одинаковыми названиями в 1?

Tags: строки, excel, csv, макросы, объединение

Есть .csv файл с большим списком товаров. Часть товаров сгруппированы друг за другом и отличаются одним полем (фактически это один и тот же товар, который имеет различные свойства).

```
ID  NAME    PRICE   DESC
3630     лодка Адмирал 280  80.0000 св 1
3630     лодка Адмирал 280  80.0000 св 2
3630     лодка Адмирал 280  80.0000 св 3
```

Как объединить такие товары в один, записав все различающиеся поля  в одно вида: `св 1;св 2;св 3` ?

```
ID  NAME    PRICE   DESC
3630     лодка Адмирал 280  80.0000 св 1;св 2;св 3
```

Пробую записать в столбце так `=ЕСЛИ(A2=A1;B101894&"; "&X2;X2)` и размножить на все строки, но получаю предупреждение о циклической ссылке.. Почему?

Comment: напишите проще макрос в vba, который будет сравнивать строки по схожести первых строк и расхожести последней.

Comment: @Denis я не знаком с макросами - подскажите, плз, если знаете как

Comment: Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (галка напротив выбранного ответа).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Желаемого результата можно достичь в два этапа:

1. Объединяем (группируем) товары по полю **NAME** создав сводную таблицу

[image: Результат группировки]

2. С помощью функции ***MergeIfUniq***  объединяем поля с описанием

[image: Вызов функции **_MergeIfUniq_**]

3. Финальный результат

[image: Финальный результат]

4. Код функции ***MergeIfUniq*** взять с http://www.planetaexcel.ru/techniques/7/205/ и добавлено условие, исключающее дублирование полей с описаниями

   ```
   Function MergeIfUniq (TextRange As Range, SearchRange As Range, Condition As String)

       Dim Delimeter As String, i As Long
       Delimeter = ", " 'символы-разделители (можно заменить на пробел или ; и т.д.)

       'если диапазоны проверки и склеивания не равны друг другу - выходим с ошибкой
       If SearchRange.Count <> TextRange.Count Then
           MergeIfUniq = CVErr(xlErrRef)
           Exit Function
       End If

       'проходим по все ячейкам, проверяем условие и собираем текст в переменную OutText
       'исключаем дублирование в переменной OutText повторящихся значений ячеек
       For i = 1 To SearchRange.Cells.Count

          If (SearchRange.Cells(i) Like Condition) And _
               (InStr(1, OutText, TextRange.Cells(i), vbTextCompare) = 0) Then _
               OutText = OutText & TextRange.Cells(i) & Delimeter
       Next i

       'выводим результаты без последнего разделителя
       MergeIfUniq = Left(OutText, Len(OutText) - Len(Delimeter))  

   End Function
   ```

PS.
Тестировалось на следующих данных

```
ID      Name                Price   Desk    
3630    лодка Адмирал 280   800 000 св 2
3630    лодка Адмирал 280   800 000 св 3
3631    лодка Тайфун        700 000 св 1
3631    лодка Тайфун        700 000 св 2
3631    лодка Тайфун        700 000 св 3
3631    лодка Тайфун        700 000 св 4
3631    лодка Тайфун        700 000 св 5
3620    лодка Оптимист      400 000 св 99
3620    лодка Оптимист      400 000 св 91
3620    лодка Оптимист      400 000 св 92
3631    лодка Тайфун        700 000 св 5
3631    лодка Тайфун        700 000 св 5
```

Comment: здесь принято давать **полный** ответ, а ссылки приводить лишь в качестве дополнения/иллюстрации.

Answer (score 0):

Привет.
Вот что у меня получилось:

```
    Sub Макрос()
start:
    For Each element In Range("a2:a8")
        If element.Value = "" Then
            Exit Sub
        ElseIf element.Value = element.Offset(1, 0) Then
            tmp = element.Offset(0, 3).Value & "; " & element.Offset(1, 3)
            element.Offset(0, 3).Value = tmp
            Rows(element.Row + 1).Select
            Selection.Delete
            GoTo start
        Else
        End If
    Next element
End Sub
```

Если нужно, могу выложить файл с примером.